# Apply Css Style while creating Dynamic Table

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

Here is my problem:

- When I create my table in C#, I would like to add different CSS style to each cell.

  while (DR.Read())
          {

  ```
      TableRow linha1 = new TableRow();
      cel1 = new TableCell();
      cel2 = new TableCell();
      cel3 = new TableCell();
      cel4 = new TableCell();

      cel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(DR.GetValue(0).ToString()));
      cel2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(DR.GetValue(1).ToString()));
      cel3.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(DR.GetValue(2).ToString()));
      cel4.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(DR.GetValue(3).ToString()));


      linha1.Controls.Add(cel1);
      linha1.Controls.Add(cel2);
      linha1.Controls.Add(cel3);
      linha1.Controls.Add(cel4);
      Tab_artigos_all.Controls.Add(linha1);
  }
  ```

Comment: No, this isn't your problem, this is your goal. What have you tried so far? Adding styles to asp.net controls is really a trivial thing, covered by multiple articles on the internet...What exactly is your problem then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its actually pretty easy.

```
cel1.Style["CSSPROPERTY"] = "SomeValue"
```

or

```
cel1.Attributes.Add("class", "CSSCLASSNAME");
```

That oughtta do it

Comment: Thank you very much.
 " cel1.Attributes.Add("class", "CSSCLASSNAME");" - that is what i wanted to find

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
cel1.Attributes.Add("class", "className");
```

or

```
cel1.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the answers above, for sure.  But you can also use the format of

```
cel1.Style(HtmlTextWriterStyle.FontSize) = 9
```

for example.  Autocomplete drop-downs will obviously give you a list of possible values to use along with **HtmlTextWriterStyle** if you're in Visual Studio.